# "This RadioGroup layout or its RelativeLayout parent is possibly useless"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, adt

I have RelativeLayout view with RadioGroup inside. I'm trying to embed RadioGroup into RelativeLayout. So to add elements to my Layout. My code goes here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rg1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Example1"
        android:checked="true"
    />

    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Example2"    
        android:checked="true"
    />
</RadioGroup>
```

Doing this shows an exception:

```
This RadioGroup layout or its RelativeLayout parent is possibly useless
```

How can I solve this warning?

Comment: Is `RadioGroup` the only thing you have inside your `RelativeLayout`? If so, it would be useless. Also, it's just a warning so it could be ignored and still run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this warning is shown when you have a Layout with only one element inside.

For example a LinearLayour with only one LinearLayour inside (this last one could have many Views) would be useless, because it doesn't serve of any layout purposes (the purpose of a layout is distributing views).

In your specific case you could get rid of the outer `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, It is just a warning to reduce view hierarchy.

If you layout has only Single RadioGroup the use the following code

```
<RadioGroup

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rg1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Example1"
        android:checked="true"
    />

    <RadioButton 
        android:id="@+id/r2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Example2"    
        android:checked="true"
    />
</RadioGroup>
```